# How to establish a one-to-one relationship

Tags: php, orm, yii

I'm building a system where I want to separate some data from a lot of other tables.

I got a lot of objects that need to have the attributes: title, short-description, long-description. I stored those in another table called `Info`.

So in Yii you can build your models from the database. From these models it is able to make the CRUD or the forms for it. What I want is that when I generate the forms, I can have the one-to-one related objects in the form aswell.

For example the tables:

`Community` with two foreign keys: `Info_id`(FK) and `Contact_id`(FK).
`Contact` (contact fields) with properties `Phone` and `Address`.
`Info` (info fields) with properties `Name`, `Short description` and `Description`.

With **autogenerated** (with Gii, if possible) the form for `Community`:

```
Fieldset <Contact>
textfield Phone
textfield Address

Fieldset <Info>
textfield Name
textfield Short description
textfield Description
```

Is this possible using Yii's autogenerator `Gii`? Or a way to get it into it without changing everything (the controllers and forms) manually?

It's pretty 'weird' in my opinion that there is not the slightest implementation for a one-to-one relation. Or should I make the fields inside every object? And why would that be better?

Answer (score 0):

The deafult giix templates won't do this for you, you can always [create your own templates](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii#extending-gii), I also recommend [giix](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/giix/) which handles this and many-to-many also, among other things.

Comment: What you're trying to say is that the gii (instead of giix?) code generator does not do this by default? And you say that instead of gii I should use giix? Is that correct?

Comment: not instead, giix is a gii template collection, that has what you are looking for.